# Как сделать так, чтобы при :hover изменялся background у :before этого элемента?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть стрелка:

```
<div class="leftArrow arrow"><p>Предыдущий товар</p></div>
```

У неё такие стили:

```
.arrow {
   position: absolute;
   top: 43%;
   width: 42px;
   height: 94px;
}
.leftArrow {
    left: -30%;
}
.arrow p {
    width: 200px;
    color: #9B9B9B;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: 100 20px dindisplay;
}
.leftArrow p {
    padding: 37px 0px;
}
.leftArrow p:before {
    content: '';
    padding: 38.5px 42px 38.5px 0px;
    background: url(../img/arrows.png) no-repeat center left;
}
```

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы при наведении на `.leftArrow p` изменялся `background` у `.leftArrow p:before`?

Comment: `.leftArrow p:hover:before`

Comment: пример http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxYBeP

Answer (score 5):

Необходимо дописать:

```
.leftArrow p:hover:before {
    background: ... ;
}
```